# Layout Chat -Inverter o lado da minha mensagem

Tags: android, layout

Então eu estou começando agora fazer a atividade do chat não tenho nenhum código ainda, mais pensando no processo me veio uma dúvida... Praticamente do jeito que irei fazer Todas mensagem enviadas ficarão de um lado só, oque eu quero é que ela fique igual a do whatsapp ou outros inúmeros apk de mensagem por ai, Todas mensagem recebidas fiquem do lado esquerdo e minha mensagem do lado direito.

*Estou usando firebase.

Comment: pra mim, o mais que certo seria que esse chat seja um webview, dae, quando ja tiver acesso aos textos digitados, logicamente ja vai ter de saber de qual usuário é que tá mandando e qual tá recebendo, dae, como é um webview, voce trabalha com `<div class='sender' style='text-align: right;'>` e  `<div class='receiver' style='text-align: leftt;'>`, ou como vc quiser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem, eu fiz da seguinte forma: 
Usando um RecyclerView, eu fiz dois ViewHolders com seus respectivos layouts em xml para as mensagens (Por exemplo, ViewHolderMensagemDireita e ViewHolderMensagemEsquerda). E, na hora de vincular os dados (no onBindViewHolder), você deve achar alguma forma de identificar qual mensagem é sua e qual mensagem é das outras pessoas (você pode comparar IDs, etc)...

```
public class RecyclerViewChat extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Mensagem> mensagemList;
    private Context context;
    private Usuario usuario;

    private static final int OWN_MESSAGE = 0;
    private static final int OTHERS_MESSAGE = 1;

    public RecyclerViewChat(List<Mensagem> mensagemList, Context context, Usuario usuario) {
        this.mensagemList = mensagemList;
        this.context = context;
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Comparação para saber se é a msg do user ou dos outros...No caso eu usei o nome dele, mas pode usar o que quiser
        if(mensagemList.get(position).getName().equals(usuario.getName())){
            return OWN_MESSAGE;
        } else {
            return OTHERS_MESSAGE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType==OWN_MESSAGE){
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_chat_right, parent, false);
            return new RightChatViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_chat_left, parent, false);
            return new LeftChatViewHolder(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // left = dos outros
        if(holder instanceof LeftChatViewHolder){

            ((LeftChatViewHolder)holder).msg = mensagemList.get(position);
            ((LeftChatViewHolder)holder).userName.setText(mensagemList.get(position).getName());
            ((LeftChatViewHolder)holder).message.setText(mensagemList.get(position).getMessage());

            // right = sua msg
        } else if(holder instanceof RightChatViewHolder){
            ((RightChatViewHolder)holder).msg = mensagemList.get(position);
            ((RightChatViewHolder)holder).userName.setText(mensagemList.get(position).getName());
            ((RightChatViewHolder)holder).message.setText(mensagemList.get(position).getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mensagemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public static class LeftChatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView userName;
        private TextView message;

        private Mensagem msg;

        public LeftChatViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_adapter_left_username);
            message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_adapter_left_mensagem);

        }
    }

    public static class RightChatViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView userName;
        private TextView message;

        private Mensagem msg;

        public RightChatViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_adapter_right_username);
            message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_adapter_right_mensagem);

        }
    }
    // add um novo objeto mensagem...
    public void setNewMessage(Mensagem message){
        if(mensagemList==null){
            mensagemList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.mensagemList.add(message);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
     // pega a posição da ultima mensagem
     public Integer lastPos(){
        return mensagemList.size()-1;
    }

}
```

Não se esqueça de usar um `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter.lastPos());` na activity sempre que for add uma nova mensagem onde o método lastPos acha a última posição da listagem de mensagens (e o recyclerView é o objeto do tipo RecyclerView e o adapter é um objeto do tipo RecyclerViewChat que te passei) e por fim dá um scroll automático pra ela...É pra facilitar as coisas.

Comment: Entendi, acrescentei que estou usando firebase, como ainda não cheguei nessa parte vou deixar a pergunta aberta antes de dar Aceite na sua,Obrigado!

Comment: Voce vai enviar a lista de mensagens no construtor dessa classe que eu passei...
Não vai mudar nada ela.
Voce pode fazer um teste e criar mensagens como objetos gerados pelo java mesmo só para fins de teste...entende?